# how to install or revert to an older version of Qt?

Tags: apt, software-installation, compiling, qt

I have Qt 5.7.

I need Qt 5.6.

Can I revert my currently installed version back to 5.6, or can I install 5.6 beside it using apt/the repos? Or will I have use the Qt installer?

This is for compiling software to be run on a remote server which does not yet have 5.7.

Comment: find the qt 5.7 package, sudo apt remove ..., go find the qt 5.6 deb somewhere, sudo gdebi ....

Answer (score 1):

https://download.qt.io/archive/qt/5.6/5.6.2/

Set the downloader as executable, run it, choose a directory, and from QtCreator, goto the options and set the qt version manually.

Answer (score 0):

you can unistall it with Synaptic package manager in Ubuntu and install new version in it in Synaptic you tick Qt or you can use apt-get

```
sudo apt-get remove yourpackagename
```

With below command you can remove package but keep configuration file.

```
sudo apt-get remove package_name
```

if you want to remove configuration file and remove package use:

```
sudo apt-get purge package_name
```

for install use:

```
sudo apt-get install package_name
```